# Best way to implement floor and fract for floating point numbers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, optimization, floating-point

`floor` in Haskell is defined only for the `RealFrac` typeclass. I don't really know much about this typeclass and the rest of my code only uses floating point numbers.

I can't find any function for casting a `Float` to an `Int`. If there were then `floor` would be equivalent to `fromIntegral (fromFloating x)` and `fract` would be defined as

```
fract x = x - floor x
```

However, as I said, I haven't found any function that does anything like what I want `fromFloating` to do. So this is the only way I could think of for implementing `fract`:

```
fract x 
    | x < 0 = 1 - fract (abs x)
    | x < 1 = x
    | otherwise = fract (x - 1)
```

and then of course `floor x` would be `x - fract x`. The algorithm above, however, is O(n) and it's going to drastically slow things down, so I'm hoping there's a way to do this that is constant time.

Comment: `floor` function has the following type `floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`, so you can instantiate it to take a `Float` and return an `Int`  (https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=floor)

Comment: Notably, both Float and Double are instances of RealFrac, so your concerns that you use them instead of using RealFrac is misplaced.

Comment: Why not `fract = snd . properFraction`? (`fract = \x -> x - fromIntegral (floor x)` has the correct type and almost does what you want, but doesn't work for negative numbers). It is entirely unnecessary to 'cast' a `Float` to an `Int` here (whatever 'cast' actually means to you).

Comment: "floor in Haskell is defined only for the RealFrac typeclass." I suggest you learn what a typeclass is. Most likely you can still use this for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, `floor` is already implemented for floating point numbers, and `frac` is straightforward; this code compiles:

```
aDouble :: Double
aDouble = -5.675

aFloat :: Float
aFloat = 10.675

frac :: RealFrac a => a -> a
frac x = x - fromIntegral (floor x :: Integer)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "aDouble is"
  print aDouble
  putStrLn "frac(aDouble) is"
  print (frac aDouble)
  putStrLn "aFloat is"
  print aFloat
  putStrLn "frac(aFloat) is"
  print (frac aFloat)
```

and produces:

```
$ runhaskell /tmp/a.hs
aDouble is
-5.675
frac(aDouble) is
0.3250000000000002
aFloat is
10.675
frac(aFloat) is
0.6750002
```